# Still struggling with this... Why can't I get fade on mouse out to work?

Tags: javascript

```
let icon = document.getElementById('loginIcon');
let content = document.getElementById('loginField');
let head = document.getElementById('header');
let contentVisible = content.style.visibility='visible';

icon.onclick = function() {
if (content.style.visibility='visible') {
content.classList.toggle('fade');
}
else {
content.classList.toggle('fade');
}
}

head.mouseleave = function hideLogin() {
if (contentVisible) {
content.classList.toggle('fade');
}
}
```

The CSS (fade) works when I click the login icon, but the login field does not disappear when I leave the header as I've instructed. Is my code garbage or is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to use `onmouseleave`, whereas you're only using `mouseleave`.

Try this:

```
head.onmouseleave = function hideLogin() {
  if (contentVisible) {
    content.classList.toggle('fade');
  }
}
```

A preferable way to do this would be attach an event listener explicitly like this:

```
head.addEventListener('mouseleave', e => {
   if (contentVisible) {
        content.classList.toggle('fade');
   }
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseleave_event

Comment: Awesome. So now it's triggering the fade toggle. The issue is that every time I leave the header now, it fades in and out. I only want it to fade out and make it so the user has to click the login icon again to have the login fields reappear. That's why (at lease this is what I'm trying to accomplish) I put the "if (contentVisible)" thinking that if contentVisible is true, the toggle will fade, if not, it wont. But the condition doesn't seem to work. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

in your code `contentVisible` isn't a boolean since you are assign to it the value of the style, about the onClick function it does almost the same in the `if` and the `else` part. for this reason it can be generalized as `content.classList.toggle('fade');`, about the function in mouseover, it do almost the same as the "click" function, so, you can generalize this separated function in just one.

About the way you add the listeners, it's ok, but it's better if you add it with addEventListener because in this way you can add more than one event of the same type to one element.

I made a little refactor to your code for the reasons I write above.

```js
let icon = document.getElementById('loginIcon');
let content = document.getElementById('loginField');
let head = document.getElementById('header');
let contentVisible = content.style.visibility === 'visible';


head.onmouseenter = function hideLogin() {
  if (contentVisible) {
    content.classList.toggle('fade');
  }
}

// Another way
icon.addEventListener("click", toggleContentVisibility);
head.addEventListener("mouseenter", toggleContentVisibility);

function toggleContentVisibility(event) {
  if(event.type === "click") {
    content.classList.toggle('fade');
  }
  
  if(event.type === "mouseenter" && contentVisible) {
    content.classList.toggle('fade');
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div id="loginIcon">
  Login icon
</div>
<nav id="header">
  <div id="loginField">
    Login field
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm so apprehensive to change the code now because I finally have it working enough :P. If you look at the answer before yours, I followed what he said and got it working. The only issue is that now the "onmouseleave" event triggers every time the user leaves the header. I just want it to trigger ONLY if the "content" is visible. Can't seem to get that piece to work.

Comment: in this case, you need onmouseenter, I will do an example.

Comment: Are you sure...? I'm not doubting you, but I tried onmouseenter and all it does is reverse the issue: Instead of the login menu fading in and out when you exit the header, it does so when you enter the header. It seems like my JS is not working properly in terms of the condition being that the content (login field) is visible. Is this because contentVisible is not boolean? If so, is there a way I can assign a value of true to contentVisible when the content is visible and false otherwise?

Comment: you can first add the visibility with content.style.visibility='visible'; and in contentVisibility you can do let contentVisible = content.style.visibility === 'visible';

Comment: Probably is because the inconsistency in the logic of the onClick, if you can made a codesanbox with the error I can help you more easy.